# error while creating new web application in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

i am getting  error while creating new web application in sharepoint 2010.
first i got this issue:
"There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"

then i did iisreset
after this when i tried to create new application i got following issue:

"This content database requires upgrade and could not be attached in this operation. Use either the [stsadm -o addcontentdb] command or [Mount-SPContentDatabase] cmdlet instead"

few days before, it was working fine.i dont know what could be reason.first time i got this error.

help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/aba647cf-b502-480a-ba4c-3a46cbbf7d54) issue seems to come while you migrate your application to different farm.

Try below steps:

1. Backup SP 2007 database on SP 2007 SQL server
2. Copy backup file to SP 2010 SQL server
3. Restore the backup to a new database on the SP2010 SQL server.
4. On the SP 2010 create a new web application through central admin
5. Drop the database for the newly created web app (in central admin)
6. Run the stsadm command listed above referencing the database you restored from the SP 2007 instance

Try this this as well.

Under Command Prompt (with elevated permission) navigate to the SharePoint hive directory…
cd "\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN

Enter the following command in (changing your database name and new SharePoint website’s URL to the new one…

> stsadm -o addcontentdb -url
>   http://cssp02-staging -databasename
>   sharepoint.navigation.content
>   -databaseserver cssql03-staging -preserveolduserexperience true

Comment: hi ashish,
i am not migrating my application to different farm.
 i am just creating new web application on sharepoint foundation 2010.

Comment: try with running stsadm command as I mentioned, hopefully that way you can create site and associate content db with that.

Comment: finally my problem resolved.
i restarted the sharepoint server and problem resolved.
thanx ashish for your response.